# total time taken by the program to execute basic operations

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time, execution

i want to know the time taken by the program to execute.
and also i don't want the time taken by the user to give input.
only time for basic operations.
Like we need to compare the efficiency of two algorithms.
Basic Operation like

```
a+b
a-b
a*b
a/b
a<b
a>b
a=b
```

and more.
thanks

Comment: good for you. what's your question?

Comment: time taken by the program to execute ??

Comment: use stopwatch. (Silly unswer to silly question)

Comment: just don't comment if you don't wanna help

Comment: @Ansul - A modern PC will be able to execute 3-4 of these instructions per clock tick (0.3 nanoseconds). You will never be able to measure them individually.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use a profiler, then this can act as a poor-man's profiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

clock_t start = clock();
/* Code you want timed here */
printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Courtesy: Julienne Walker aka Narue

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time). This measures CPU usage and consequently won't take into account user input times etc.

> The time command runs the specified program command with the given
>   arguments. When command finishes, time writes a message to standard
>   error giving timing statistics about this program run. These
>   statistics consist of (i) the elapsed real time between invocation and
>   termination, (ii) the user CPU time (the sum of the tms_utime and
>   tms_cutime values in a struct tms as returned by times(2)), and (iii)
>   the system CPU time (the sum of the tms_stime and tms_cstime values in
>   a struct tms as returned by times(2))

Comment: it also gives time taken by the user to give input

Comment: @AnshulGupta “(ii) the user CPU time (the sum of the tms_utime and tms_cutime values in a struct tms as returned by times(2))” does not include the time the program was stalled waiting on input.

Comment: @Anshul - no. It'll provide a breakdown as Pascal has indicated